Child born in UK to Indonesian parents with settlement status
My wife and I are both Indonesians, and my child was born a couple of months ago. We are applying for Indonesian passport. But I know my child has acquired automatic British citizenship because I have Indefinite Leave to Remain. I'm thinking of getting UK passport for my child as well.
But I also know Indonesia doesn't allow dual citizenship. What happens in this case, since my child is already British?
Thanks

Nothing, probably, unless Indonesia asks for proof of renunciation of any other citizenships https://www.gov.uk/renounce-british-nationality

@Traveller thank you for the reply. After some more research I found that indeed after turning 18 my child would have renounce the British citizenship. But I wonder what happens now if I were to actively get her the British passport.

In most countries the laws say that your actions around citizenship can have consequences for you. That is YOUR actions, not YOUR PARENTS' actions. So until their 18th birthday or whatever date Indonesia calls them fully responsible adults, they might have to make a decision.
